Weighted Average at Row Level in Power BI Matrix Visual
Trying to develop a Power BI matrix visual which will show raw data in row level.
I was able to show row level data by adding the Ranked column to the rows section of visual. Then in the total section, I need a custom calculation. Weighted Average Stipend is needed.
The formula is :
Weighted Stipend Average = SUM(Stipend * Number of Assistant)/SUM(Number of Assistant)

Here,
Stipend means various stipend like Teaching, Research, Graduate etc
Number of Assistant means number of teaching assistant, research assistant, graduate assistant etc
I tried using measure but I couldn't add measure in row level for every sub-category.
Here is the table structure:

Here is the visual set up in Power BI:

